# Indirect call of a column from different sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I know how to use the indirect formula in a sheet itself.

```
=INDIRECT(CHAR(ROW(A5))&ROW(A5))
```

However, I am having hard time manipulating this to find a formula from different sheet called 'sheet1'

I am trying to retrieve value in B3 of Sheet1 using indirect formula. Any help is appreciated.

Please note, going forward (I plan to drag this formula down) I plan to manipulate rows and columns so I do want both of them (rows and columns) as variable values.

Eg: NOT indirect('Sheet1'!B3) but rather something like indirect('Sheet1!'&char(row(a5))...etc) which is not working for me.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi Scott, Thanks for the answer but how can it be manipulated?

eg: if I want the column to increase by +3...would it simply be 
=INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!" &CHAR(ROW(B3)+3)&ROW(B3)) ?

Thanks!

Comment: That depends on what coulmn you are shooting for.  To get column A you would need to add 62.  B add 63 and so forth.  There may be a better formula than what you are trying.  If you show some data and what you are trying to accomplish a better formula may be suggested.

Comment: For example to get the same, You could do `='Sheet1'!$A3`  this would keep the column static while the rows change when dragged.  As I read your formula it does the same thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`=INDIRECT(CHAR(ROW(A5))&ROW(A5))` just returns `#REF`

do not use something like `CHAR()` to build a "A1" address. Better use R1C1:

```
=INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!R3C2",0)
```

to make the row dragable:

```
=INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!R"&ROW()&"C2",0)
```

or to fit the columns:

```
=INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!R3C"&COLUMN(),0)
```

or for both:

```
=INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!R"&ROW()&"C"&COLUMN(),0)
```