# Indirect Function Excel

Tags: excel

I am rather new to excel formulas. I am using the Indirect function and it is working properly when I manually enter the formula into the data validation source. What I would like to do is to copy it down the entire row. I am currently using the formula: `=INDIRECT($Y$2)` Referencing Column `(Y)` and row `(2)`.

After some research, it appears that I can use the row function to accomplish this, but I am unsure how to include that into the formula I already have.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you provide a little bit more info about what you've done, what you're trying to do, and what has gone wrong?

Comment: see  [Auto-fill formula that references numerical worksheet names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34432128/auto-fill-formula-that-references-numerical-worksheet-names/34432323#34432323).

Comment: I have two drop down lists on one of my spreadsheets. The first being standard "static" selections. IE.....Blue, Green, Red......and so on. The second drop down is dependent on what you select on the first list and returns a certain range of results based on your selection instead of all of them. I am pulling these just from another sheet contained within the same workbook. When I try to copy down the formula to the next row down it doesn't increase to the next row number. In this case it would need to be: =INDIRECT($Y$3). I can accomplish this manually going into each cell.

Comment: My answer from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34404884/indirect-call-of-a-column-from-different-sheet/34405187#34405187) may get you where you want to be...

Answer (score 2):

The issue that the OP describes is that their formulas break when they duplicate the entire row where an indirect reference is made using `=INDIRECT($Y$2)` in the data validation source of a cell.

The problem has to do with the cell reference and how the "$" symbol is used. It is described in more detail [here](http://www.notjustnumbers.co.uk/2011/05/excel-tip-dollar-sign-in-formula-fixing.html). However, the relevant information is that the symbol allows you to control how the referencing cell should behave toward the referenced cell. You can allow or prevent change to the relative positions between the two. If you want to copy/paste a referring cell you must decide if the referenced cell will be fixed or moved in the process.

fix the row and allow the column to change
`=INDIRECT($Y2)`

allow the row to change and fix the column
`=INDIRECT(Y$2)`

fix(prevent change) to both column and row
`=INDIRECT($Y$2)`

allow change to both column an row
`=INDIRECT(Y2)`

Answer (score 1):

You can put a conditional IF function into the data validation source itself. Would that be sufficient?

You will have the static choices:

`=$M$2:$M$4`

And then the variable sets of choices:

`=IF(A2="choice1",$Y$2:$Y$4,$Z$2:$Z$4)`

Note that the first cell reference in the IF statement is relative, but all others are absolute.

Answer (score 0):

To use the row the formula is on, you can use `=Indirect("Y"&row())`

Comment: Tried that, just returns the same value as what's been selected in the first dropdown list.